# Byte array slicing and mapping parts to structures

Tags: c++, arrays, network-programming, c++14, packet

I am working on network Programming. I am receiving packets through socket. 
Packet Format:  HEADER+MESSAGE'1+Message'2+...+Message'n
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWXLt.png)

header is of 16 bytes. header parts having many data members one of them is total message Count

(**msgCount**:- describe the total no of message in the packet).

There are no delimiters between the packet header and messages or between messages
themselves. One has to use the size of the header and in each individual message to determine the
start of each message.

The format of each message within a packet varies according to message type. However, regardless
of the message type, all messages start with a two-byte message size followed by a two-byte
message type.

 **MsgSize** Binary integer representing the length of the message (including the header)

 **MsgType** Binary integer representing the type of message.

I want to parse all the messages and map them to respective structures (struct) according to there msgType.

```
using namespace std;
struct Header
{
    short seqNum;
    short msgCount;
    long msgTime;
    //there are other data members also 

};
struct FindMessage
{
    short msgType;
    short msgSize;
};
struct Message1 : public FindMessage
{

    //data members.....

};
struct Message2 : public FindMessage
{

    //data members.....

};
void processPacket(char* packet)
{
    char *msgFront=NULL;
    char charMessgae;
    int size = sizeof(packet);
    int readDone = 16;
    Header hdr;  //struct
    memcpy(&hdr, packet,16);         // size of header is 16 byte
    int msgCount = hdr.msgCount;
    for (int i =0; i < msgCount; i++)
    {
        FindMessage *newMessage;    // struct
        packet = packet + 15;        //  moving pointer to the end of header part
        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            msgFront = msgFront+packet[15 + j];
        }

        newMessage = (FindMessage*)msgFront;    // taking first 4 byte of remaing Packet which containg msgsize and msgType;

        for (int k = readDone; k < newMessage->msgSize; k++)
        {
            charMessgae = charMessgae + packet[k];
        }

        switch (newMessage->msgType)
        {
        case 1: 
            Message1 *msg = (Message1*)charMessgae;
            //using Message1 struct members...
            break;
        case 2:
            Message2 *msg = (Message2*)charMessgae;
            //using Message1 struct members...
            break;
        }
        readDone += newMessage->msgSize;
        memset(&charMessgae,0,sizeof(charMessgae));
        memset(newMessage, 0, sizeof(newMessage)); // setting memory to zero to assigne new value;

    }
}
```

basically i want to do byte array slicing of different size and then map them to different structures.

Comment: It is unclear to me what the question is?

Comment: `char charMessgae` probably meant to be `char* charMessgae`. Also, it's never initialized.